# Python dealing with string-matching

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

There's a string like that:

```
mystr = 'account_id 37318 not found'
```

I'm wondering how to write an condition better than:

```
if 'account_id' not in str and 'not found' not in str:
    doSomething()
```

I guess there must be something like:

```
if 'account_id' + %any substring% + 'not found' not in str:
   doSomething()
```

Probably a regular expression might help, but I'm not good with using it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: firstly ... `str` is a very bad variable name.

Comment: oh, yeah, sure) it's just an example. I'll edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and don't use builtin keywords as variable names.

```
if all(i not in s for i in ('not found', 'account_id')):
```

Example:

```
>>> tr = 'account_id 37318 not found'
>>> tr1 = '2735723'
>>> all(i not in tr for i in ('not found', 'account_id'))
False
>>> all(i not in tr1 for i in ('not found', 'account_id'))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help.

```
import re
string = 'account_id 37318 not found'

match = re.search(r'\baccount_id\b.*?\bnot found\b',string)
if match:
    print 'Do something'
else:
    print 'Do nothing'
```

Let me know if it helps :).

Comment: probably better to use `\baccount_id\b.*?\bnot found\b` (not need to describe the start and the end of the string and starting a pattern with a literal string is always more efficient).